# Using generics in arguments of an Exception

Tags: java, generics, exception

I'm trying to store a collection of generic objects within an `Exception` and am having troubles figuring out the generics. Specifically, I'm using Hibernate Validator and would like to save the collected list of violations within an exception for processing in another layer of the application. Here's an example:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validate(user);
if (violations.size() > 0) {
    throw new ValidationException("User details are invalid", violations);
}
```

In Eclipse, the `throws` line is showing the constructor undefined and is suggesting I change the constructor signature to `ValidationException(String, Set<ConstraintViolation<User>>`. Here's ValidationException:

```
public class ValidationException extends Exception {
    private Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations;

    public ValidationException() {
    }
    public ValidationException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
    public ValidationException(String msg, Throwable cause) {
        super(msg, cause);
    }
    public ValidationException(String msg, Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations) {
        super(msg);
        this.violations = violations;
    }
    public Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> getViolations() {
        return violations;
    }
}
```

However, I want to keep `ValidationException` generic so that I can use it for more than just `User` validations. I've tried `Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends Object>>` as well, but get the same results.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why do you need the ConstrainsViolation to be generic in the first place? Can't you just create a separate Class inheriting an AbstractBase for each possible Violation?

Comment: I thought that using a generic Exception type would be a good idea, but as @axtavt mentioned, Exceptions can't be generic. See this FAQ: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ301

Comment: @Falcon: `ConstraintsViolation` is part of the Hibernate Validation package and uses generics. It isn't a class of my own.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to declare the violations set parameter as `Set<? extends ConstraintViolation<?>>`:

```
public ValidationException(String msg, 
                           Set<? extends ConstraintViolation<?>> violations) {
  super(msg);
  this.violations = Collections.unmodifiableSet(
      new HashSet<ConstraintViolation<?>>(violations));
}
```

Then everything should work as expected.

This has the additional benefit of defensively copying the `Set` you're given, ensuring that the exception's internal `Set` can't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

One ugly approach would be to use unchecked cast:

```
public class ValidationException extends Exception {
    private Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations;

    @SuppressWarning("unchecked")
    public <T> ValidationException(String msg, Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations) {
        super(msg);
        this.violations = (Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>)(Set<?>) violations;
    } 
}
```

As far as I understand, unchecked cast is completely safe in this case, so that `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` is absolutely legal.

From other hand, this constructor can't be called with `Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>` as a parameter.

Comment: Ugly is right! But it looks like it works. Not getting compile errors anymore. Thanks!

Comment: Whether the cast is safe depends on where (and how) the Set is used outside of the exception object. `Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> is not a supertype of `Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>`, since the latter one only admits elements of type `ConstraintViolation<T>` (and its users may depend on this to be the case), while the former admits `ConstrainViolation`s of any type (even mixed ones) (which means you could put a `ConstraintViolation<String>` in this Set).  In this use for the exception supposedly the creators of the exception create it and the catcher only iterates, so it will not really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the requirement is that the set must be homogeneous - `violations` must be of type  `Set<ConstraintViolation<X>>` for some `X`.

The most natural way to do that is to make `ValidationException` generic:

```
public class ValidationException<T> extends Exception
    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations;
    public ValidationException(String msg, Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations)
```

Of course, Java does not allow that for subtypes of Throwable, for reasons beyond type system. This is not our fault, so we are not guilty of inventing some workaround:

```
public class ValidationException extends Exception
{
    static class SetConstraintViolation<T> extends HashSet<ConstraintViolation<T>>
    {
        SetConstraintViolation(Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations)
        {
            super(violations);
        }
    }

    // this is homogeneous, though X is unknown
    private SetConstraintViolation<?> violations;

    public <T> ValidationException(String msg, Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations)
    {
        super(msg);
        this.violations = new SetConstraintViolation<T>(violations);
    }

    public <T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> getViolations()
    {
        return (Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>)violations;
    }
}

void test()
{
    Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> v = ...;
    ValidationException e = new <User>ValidationException("", v);
    Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> v2 = e.getViolations();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Pswd>> v3 = e.getViolations();
    Set<? extends ConstraintViolation<?>> v4 = e.getViolations();
}
```

Note: the cast in `getViolations()` is only safe, if call site supplied correct `T`, as in the case of `v2`. In the case of v3, the cast is wrong - the compiler didn't warn us in vain.

The call site probably doesn't know, and doesn't care about, the exact `T`, as in the case of v4. The call site can cast the violations, a homogeneous collection of a certain unknown type, to a more general readonly type with wildcards. That is quite awkward. If case `v4` is the most frequent use case, we should provide a method that simply returns `Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>`. We can't directly return `violations`, that's unsafe. A copy is required. If `v4` is the only use case, the this solution really becomes the same solution proposed by previous responders.

Comment: thanks for the very thorough answer! Your solution seems to add excess complexity. Is there a some reason it is a better approach than something simpler like that suggested by @ColinD?

Comment: I imposed the homogeneous requirement, for thought experiment if nothing else. It's probably not what you care about.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that a `Set<ConstraintViolation<User>>` can only contain objects of type `ConstraintViolation<User>`, while your argument type `Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>` can contain violations of any type (so, it is a mixed collection). Thus, this is not a subtype. I think (did not try) you could declare the constructor as

```
public <T> ValidationException(String msg, Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations);
```

but then you still have the problem that the variable in your exception can't have such a type. You could copy the contents of the parameter in a new Set, use Collections.unmodifiedSet() to wrap it, or do the ugly cast mentioned by axtavt to get around this. Here my preferred way:

```
public <T> ValidationException(String msg, Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations) {
   this.violations = Collections.unmodifiableSet(violations);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a Java `throwable` cannot be made generic, because owing to type erasure a `catch` block cannot test the generic parameters of the exceptions that it catches. You will have to do it the old-fashioned way, with casts and whatnot.

You can add a method to automagically do the cast:

```
class ConstraintViolation extends SomeException {
  Constraint c;
  «T extends Constraint» T getConstraint() { return (T) c};
} 

…
UserConstraint uc = theViolation.getConstraint();
```

The compiler will warn you that it cannot actually perform the cast you are asking it to do, but that's cool.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validate(user);
if (violations.size() > 0) {
    throw new ValidationException("User details are invalid", (Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>) (Set<? extends ConstraintViolation<?>>) violations);
}
```